# How to mention user inputs?

Tags: discord.js, arguments, bots

I'm trying to figure out this dumb line but cannot find a way.. so basically if the command is `!clear 5` I want the bot to return "all 5 messages has been cleared" after deleting of course. ${message.mentions.users.first()} returns unspecfied

```
async execute(message, args){
        if(message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")){
            if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Bruh enter a amount of messages to clear');
            if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send('Bruh enter a **number**');
            if(args[0] > 100) return message.channel.send('bruh you cant clear more than 100 messages');
            if(args[0] < 1) return message.channel.send('bruh you have to delete atleast one message or imma go sleep');

            await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages => {
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
                message.channel.send(`all ${message.mentions.users.first()} messages have been cleared bruh!`).then(msg => {
                    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)
                })
            })
        }
         else {
             message.channel.send('bruh you dont have required permissions to use this command!')
         }
    }
```

Comment: In StackOverflow, we do not simply create code for you. You have to show what you have already tried before asking. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your added code I can see what went wrong. You are currently using `${message.mentions.users.first()}` in your return message. However that returns the first mentioned user in a message which isn't what you want. You want to return the user's argument.
Change `${message.mentions.users.first()}` to `${args[0]}`

---

(Previous answer):

---

Right, so do you have a way to process message arguments?

### If yes:

It's really simple, basically store `args[0]` in a variable like `userInput` (You don't even *have* to store it in a var, it's just a neater way of writing your code). Afterwards just return a message like

```
message.channel.send(`All ${userInput} message(s) have been cleared.`);
```

---

### If no:

I suggest you take a look at how to use user arguments in your bot **[here](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#implementation)**